# Datatable cannot be reinitialise issue in jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

This is my scenario. Onload I'm getting data from the API using Ajax, and I'm displaying it in a data table. In the same page, I have a form, after submitting, it inserts into the table and I need to display the inserted record in the datatable again.

```
 function loadApps() {
     $.ajax({
         // call the URL 
     success:function(data){
            //Problem is here initialization
        $('#mytable').datatable();
     },
     error : function() {
     }
     });
 }
```

After successful insertion I'm calling the function loadApps() again which will fetch the latest data again. How can I overcome this issue of reinitializing data table again?

I have also used 
    "bDestroy":true

But it didnt work. Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Overcome what problem? Not really clear what your specific problem is. Code shown really doesn't do much and by itself makes little sense

Comment: @Charlie..updated with my question. Plz check

Comment: You don't have to destroy.. you can add additional rows to existing dataTables.. look for `how to add new rows to datatable`

Comment: @Rajasekhar let me check and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
function loadApps() {
 $.ajax({
     // call the URL 
 success:function(data){
        //Problem is here initialization
    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#mytable')) {
       $('#mytable').DataTable().destroy();
    } else {
       $('#mytable').DataTable();
    }
 },
 error : function() {
 }
 });
}
```